replacing double quotes with backslash and double quotes
I am trying to replace a double quotes (") with back slash and double quotes (") however it's not working
echo '"hello workd"' | tr '"' '\\""'

This gives me
\hello workd\

and following  does nothing.
echo '"hello workd"' | tr '"' '\"'


tr only does 1-to-1 replacements, it can't replace 1 character with multiple characters.

Use sed for this.

Why are you doing this? Are you implementing printf "%q"? Are you trying to like "double" quote a string for some other command?

Note that if your real goal is to make a string suitable to include in a JSON literal, this is not the only transform needed, and it would be much better ot use a real JSON-aware tool like jq rather than try to build a piecemeal one-off replacement.

tr is not the right tool for this as it replaces one character with another. You may use sed like this:
echo '"hello workd"' | sed -E 's/"/\\&/g'

\"hello workd\"

In s/"/\\&/g we are matching a " and replacing with a \ followed by the full match i.e. " itself.

it works perfectly. However when I am trying append this to variable. it doesn't work something like this x+=cat plan | sed -E 's/\"/\\"/g'

even assignment does the same thing y=cat plan | sed -E 's/\"/\\"/g

To store output in a variable use: var="$(sed -E 's/\"/\\"/g file)"
